# QRegExp to extract array name and index

Tags: c++, qt

I am parsing some strings. If I encounter something like "Foo(bar)", I want to extract "Foo" and "bar"

How do I do it using QRegExp?

Comment: QString varName = "Foo(bar)";
    QRegExp rx("(.*)\((.*)\)");
    if (rx.indexIn(tvfVarName) != -1) {
       qDebug() << "ArrayName=" << rx.cap(1) << " ArrayKey=" << rx.cap(2);

Comment: With regular expressions the brackets start a capture group, thus to mach a '(' character, it must be escaped as "\(". Also the dot '.' captures everything, from experience try to use more specific options instead of the dot as far as possible.

Answer (score 3):

First thing, if you are using Qt 5 then rather use [QRegularExpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) class

> The QRegularExpression class introduced in Qt 5 is a big improvement upon QRegExp, in terms of APIs offered, supported pattern syntax and speed of execution.

Secondly, get a visual tool that helps when testing/defining regular expressions, I use an online [website](https://regexr.com/).

To get the "Foo" and "Bar" from your example, I can suggest the following pattern:

```
(\w+)\((\w+)\)
--------------
The above means: 
(\w+)  - Capture one or more word characters (capture group 1)
\(     - followed by a opening brace
(\w+)  - then capture one or more word characters (capture group 2)
\)     - followed by a closing brace
```

This pattern must be escaped for direct usage in the Qt regular expression:

```
const QRegularExpression expression( "(\\w+)\\((\\w+)\\)" );
QRegularExpressionMatch match = expression.match( "Foo(bar)" );
if( match.hasMatch() ) {
  qDebug() << "0: " << match.captured( 0 ); // 0 is the complete match
  qDebug() << "1: " << match.captured( 1 ); // First capture group
  qDebug() << "2: " << match.captured( 2 ); // Second capture group
}
```

Output is:

```
0:  "Foo(bar)"
1:  "Foo"
2:  "bar"
```

See the pattern in action online [here](http://regexr.com/462j7). Hover the mouse over the parts in the "Expression" box to see the explanations or over the "Text" part to see the result.

Comment: @PdxEngineer My answer is for Qt 5 using QRegularExpression, if you really must use QRegExp let me know and I will updated the answer.

Comment: Instead of using a website, one can use [QRegularExpression](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-regularexpression-example.html) example project. It comes directly with a standard Qt install and it is available from Qt Creator's Welcome page. There is also another example for QRegExp should someone need it. Both have the feature of producing escaped regexp for C++ source.